# Match array having set of values (in any order)

Tags: arrays, h2

Is there an efficient way to find arrays in h2 that have a specific set of values regardless of order?

Say I want to find `arr` with values 1 and 2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, arr INT ARRAY);
INSERT INTO test values (1, ARRAY[2, 1]), (2, ARRAY[2, 3, 4]);
SELECT * FROM test;
ID | ARR
1  | [2, 1]
2  | [2, 3, 4]
```

Can't use `=` since only arrays with a specific order are matched:

```sql
SELECT id, arr FROM test WHERE arr = ARRAY[1, 2];
0 rows

SELECT id, arr FROM test WHERE arr = ARRAY[2, 1];
ID | ARR
1  | [2, 1]
```

Could use `IN` and list all order combinations, but that quickly gets out of hand:

```sql
SELECT id, arr FROM test WHERE arr IN (ARRAY[1, 2], ARRAY[2, 1]);
ID | ARR
1  | [2, 1]

SELECT id, arr FROM test WHERE arr IN (
  ARRAY[2, 3, 4],
  ARRAY[2, 4, 3],
  ARRAY[3, 2, 4],
  ARRAY[3, 4, 3],
  ARRAY[4, 2, 3],
  ARRAY[4, 3, 2]
);
ID | ARR
2  | [2, 3, 4]
```

Could I somehow compare sorted `arr` values with some sorted input values? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check presence of each element in the array and length of array:

```sql
SELECT ID, ARR FROM TEST
  WHERE 2 = ANY(ARR) AND 3 = ANY(ARR) AND 4 = ANY(ARR)
  AND CARDINALITY(ARR) = 3;
```

If you need to match arrays with additional elements too, remove `AND CARDINALITY(ARR) = 3` from the query.

If you use some old version of H2 (2.1.214 or older), use `ARRAY_CONTAINS(ARR, 2)` instead of `2 = ANY(ARR)`.